# How to plot a legend with a border in R?

Tags: r, plot, legend

I'm using R to plot charts and their legends but I found some issues while drawing a legend with a border.

```
plot.new()
legend(x=0, y=.15, c("Some Text"), cex=1, pt.cex =1.4, col=c("green"), 
       bty="n", fill="green", pch=c(15, 15, 15, 17), border="black")
```

[image]

The border does not completely surround the green box. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a conflict within the `legend()` call between `fill="green"`, and `pch=c(15, 15, 15, 17)`.  If I drop the latter, I get what I think you are looking for:

```
plot.new()
legend(x=0,y=.15, c("Some Text"), cex=1,pt.cex =1.4,col=c("green"), 
       bty="n",fill="green", border="black")
```

[image]